# Youtube url to php varible from click

Tags: php, jquery, html

So i got a youtube url... which im trying to get into my database in some way...

So what i got is an image

```
<img src = "cat">
```

And i also got a youtube url

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFGWnqNf6t0
```

Then what i want is when i click on my image i want the youtube link to be inserted into a php varible so I later can insert it into my database

```
$("#img").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "php file",
});
return false;
});
```

> How am i supposed to call the varible since Im not posting the url?

For example like `$username = $_POST['username'];` when i post something but to get the youtube url instead!

Comment: `<img>` does not bear any of those; you need to do it outside the tag.

Comment: `<a href="XXX"><img....></a>` basic markup. The question is way too unclear btw.

Comment: use jquery's `attr` You can also wrap the image inside a link and attach the `href` there. Then onclick, get the value of href as `this.attr('href')`

Comment: If you just want to assign an arbitrary value to an HTML element, so that this value can then be read via JS, then you should use a _custom data attribute_.

Comment: yeah sorry my bad but it doesn't solve my issue anyways

Comment: That edit of yours `<a href = "//https:` is invalid markup; remove the opening slashes. And the "to database", makes this even more unclear and possibly too broad and the POST array; that requires a form.

Comment: Btw; just to let you know @UnknownPotato that that isn't one of my downvotes. IMHO, the question is unclear (and possibly too broad), as to how you want to use all this and in regards to a database. You have a few answers below that you'll need to post a comment under, stating that if it didn't work, how they can improve on their answer and also for you to improve on your question. The question is starting to receive too many answers that may not solve what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah im sorry my question was a bit bad explained i guess, I rewrote it so maybe it's easier to understand now @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, so you get what i was trying to achieve..

```
<img src = "cat" id = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFGWnqNf6t0"
onclick = "saveVideo(this)">
```

Then the script.... To make the id go to php

```
    function saveVideo(x)
    {

        var film = x.id;

        $.post('spelista.php', {film: film},function(data){ 

        alert(data);

        })
    }
```

And then last the php varible

```
$url = $_POST['film'];
var_dump($url);
```

And then $url is the youtube url ...
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) property like this 
HTML Code

```
<img src = "bilder/lenny.gif" data-action = "//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dsGWM5XGdg"
alt = "lenny" id = "add"   width = "40" height = "40">
```

jquery Code :-

```
 $("#add").click(function(){
    var dataprop = $(this).attr('data-action');
    //SEND IT TO AJAX NOW
    });
```

Comment: are you sure `<img>` is clickable?

Comment: @Akin anything is clickable. You don’t need to wrap elements into links to be able to react to the click in JS.

Comment: Click event is added via the `id`. It will be clickable.

Comment: That depends a bit on what the OP actually is trying to achieve. As it is now, it is unclear what he actually wants.

Comment: true @CBroe. just it won't look that way in terms of user experience

Comment: @Ivar That's for sure. Seeing *"For example like $username = $_POST['username']; when i post something but to get the youtube url instead!"* - No idea where that is coming from and should be in a form if anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters to a GET request with & and ?.

```
test.php?bookid=15&page=435
```

You can add your value with jQuery:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "spelista.php?value"= $('#idofelementwithvalue').val(),
});
return false;
});
```

Sending the href:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "spelista.php?value"= $('#idofelementwithhref').attr('href'),
});
return false;
});
```

Note: You can get teh href with `attr('href')`

I hope that awnsers your question!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you know what value comes from your Database the "action/href/value". Then, you need to use:

```
$("#add").attr("href")
```

In this way, you get the value of the action/href/value from the html element. Replace "href" with whatever is the attribute's name. After getting the value, you need to post it to your url by jQuery post method. Please see the following example:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var videoValue = $("#add").attr("href");
    $.post("spelista.php", {video: videoValue}, function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to Agam's Answer: 
Here, the image is wrapped inside a link tag. This is just to provide a better user experience. i.e making the image look clickable(the little click hand)

```
<a id="link_tag" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dsGWM5XGdg">

<img src = "bilder/lenny.gif" alt = "lenny" id = "add"   width = "40" height = "40"></a>

<script>
    $("#link_tag").click(function(){
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
            alert('This link is '+link);
        });
</script>
```

Also your link is invalid. remove the `//`